# Issues with timestamp_ltz datatypes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Observing a weird issue in Snowflake.
for below table the results for all years before 1884-01-01 00:00:00.000001000 are showing different values

```
 CREATE TABLE time_tester1(time1 TIMESTAMP_LTZ, time2 TIMESTAMP_LTZ)
 INSERT INTO time_tester1
 values('1884-01-01 00:00:00.000001000','1883-01-01 00:00:00.000001000')
```

Result

```
SELECT * FROM time_tester1

Row     TIME1                                               TIME2
1       1884-01-01 00:00:00.000001000 -05:00                1882-12-31 23:56:02.000001000 -05:00
```

this issue is observed for all years less then 1884

Comment: Your time zone parameter is probably set to GMT +5, hence the result offset.
You can verify with the following command: "show parameters like 'timezone' in session;"

Comment: but why this is happening for 1883 and not for 1884

Answer (score 3):

It seems the issue is related with "The Day of Two Noons":

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127972

If you use UTC, you will not get this result:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE time_tester1(time1 TIMESTAMP_LTZ, time2 TIMESTAMP_LTZ);
INSERT INTO time_tester1
values('1884-01-01 00:00:00.000001000','1883-01-01 00:00:00.000001000');

SELECT * FROM time_tester1;

+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| TIME1                         | TIME2                         |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1884-01-01 00:00:00.000 +0000 | 1883-01-01 00:00:00.000 +0000 |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```